# cURL: wait for response until it is processed by api

Tags: php, api, curl, methods, response

everybody,

I am using the following code for synchronizing data with an API (`$method= POST`) and then I call using the GET method (`$method= GET`) to print the result of the synchronization:

```
function sendCurl ($fileName, $method)
{
    $curl = curl_init();


        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('file' => new CURLFILE($fileName)),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "Accept: application/json."
        "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
        ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl); 


        curl_close($curl);

        return $response;
}
```

The problem is that the GET method response arrives before the API has time to process it. Therefore, when I print the response I print WAITING FOR RESPONSE and not whether it went ok or failed.

What can I do to print the ok or fail and not the WAITING FOR RESPONSE?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you elaborate? PHP code is synchronous by default. So after a curl request completes, the next one is triggered.

Comment: Depending on the API service you are using, if they are immediately responding that they received it, but it is pending... then they must have some form of webhooks that subsequently call back to your server to let you know the process is finished. If not, oh well... guess you could loop infinitely with a million curl calls till it responds that its done =p (dont do that, it was sarcastic)

Comment: thanks a lot  IncredibleHat, that's what I suspected.. and no webhooks :(  It's a pity I can accept as an answer your comment